# Font causing SSL issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ssl, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm in panic, since I installed a theme based on bootstrap 3, I run into security issues over my HTTPS protocole caused by unsecured content calls.

Here is an example :
Insecure URL: http://www.materieldirect.com/themes/theme867/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
Found in: https://www.materieldirect.com/themes/theme867/css/bootstrap.min.css

Both of my CDN and SSL provider say it comes from my CSS files making unsecured calls.
After a closer look in my bootstrap.min.css I see these lines :

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')
```

What do you guys suggest to solve this issue ?
I red somewhere I should use relative paths, shall I in this case use :

```
src:url('/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

instead of

```
src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

My major concern is about general site performance and offer best browsing experience to my visitors.
I'd like my content to be delivered over SSL only when it's required on HTPPS pages, and not make constant calls for HTTPS content to be displayed on HTTP pages as well.

Your help would be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: The src starting with `../` should be good. Are the paths OK? When trying to load the eot file directly (with your link), I end up on a "Page introuvable" page, both with http and https protocols.

Comment: Wait, I see that if I try the https, I get redirected to the http one. Or is that just the 404 page which does that?

Comment: No, wait, it happends on HTTPS pages for example : [LINK] (https://www.materieldirect.com/login?back=my-account) because the code is called from [link] (https://www.materieldirect.com/themes/theme867/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: Hmm ok, I tried to clean my cookies and cache from my browser, and now I have no more errors on the page regarding secure and unsecure code displayed on my page. I also found this bug related to prestashop : [LINK](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-11540]

Comment: A path starting with '..' *is* a relative URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little feedback about my issue, I was looking at wrong place and should have open my eyes wider. I had a non relative link for an external font :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Changed to `<link href='//fonts...`
No more issues